# Redirect ttisql output to file

Tags: oracle, timesten

I am using Oracle Timesten ttIsql utility for query execution. I want to check how much time it takes to execute Select statement using "timing" function.

For large data set, the utility takes some time to display records on screen.

Is there a way to redirect output to some file so that screen rendering time is not included in total time taken, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

how about we just use

```
ttisql -e "sql statements" > /dev/null 2>&1
```

Comment: I think your answers just as good as the one below, but I'd recommend changing our updating it to fully answer the OP's question, e.g. your example sends everything to /dev/null and not a file like they asked.  Still a good answer!

Answer (score 1):

`"ttisql -f query.sql dsn=yourdsn > output.txt`"
Here,
query.sql: This can be your query file which contains all the SQL queries that you want to execute on TimesTen database.
yourdsn= your data source name

Answer (score 1):

If your concern is that screen rendering time is distorting the timings of SQL execution then the best way to time SQL using ttIsql is to disable the formatting/display of the results while still displaying the timings:

```
ttIsql "DSN=xxx;..."
Command> timing 1;
Command> verbosity 0;
Command> prepare 1 some sql statement;
Command> execandfetch 1;
Command> close 1;
Command> free 1;
```

This will give the most accurate SQL timing however note that:

1. As with any timing you should run the same thing many times and take an average.
2. SQL operations in TimesTen often take a very short time indeed so the timings reported may have a large error variance due to other system activity.